# How can I get the expiration date of a certificate by C# code?

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate

How can I get the expiration date of a certificate by C# code?

I need to get data about a certificate in *Internet Options* (-> content -> certificates).

Comment: Be sure to accept answers by clicking the charkmark beside the one that helped.  Also many answerers browse by tag, you'll get a much better response if you add more tags (max of 5) relevant to the question...don't just make tags up though, use the autocomplete that's built-in when you're tagging.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer to let other visitors know that the answer has been given and can be used by others.

Answer (score 7):

Use X509Store class to access certificates in Windows Certificate Storages. Then check NotAfter property of the certificate of your choice, accesible via X509Certificate2 class.

[Help topic for X509Store class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.aspx) contains the sample how to enumerate certificates and read their properties.